XSIM setting points property
I cannot figure out how to set points besides the classic points=... options of the exercise environment.
Situation
Some of my exercises have a points property because they are dedicated to be evaluated and some have not. I write this info in comment of the exercise file as a metadata. I have a Python routine that fetch the number of points in the metadata of the exercise file and I define a command \ThePoints which I affect the points amount to. So in my process of inserting exercises to my main file, I need to check whether the exercise has the metadata or not, which I know by checking if \ThePoints is an empty string or not. This process is working fine for custom property but I cannot figure out why it does not work with the predefined pointsproperty.
Here is a minimal example that works somehow : the good amount of points is attributed correctly except for the exercises that have no points metadata (in this case, \ThePoints command is an empty string but for xsim it is 0 which I don't want)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}%
\RequirePackage{pyluatex}
\begin{python}
  def findpoints(f):
    with open(f+".tex","r") as fi:
      id = []
      for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("% @Points"):
          id.append(ln[2:])
    if len(id) != 0:
      return id[0].split("@Points ",2)[1]
    else:
      return ''
\end{python}
\newcommand{\FindPoints}[1]{\pyc{print(findpoints("#1"))}}
\newcommand\SetPoints[1]{\SetExerciseProperty{points}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ThePoints}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputexofiche}{ m } {%
\renewcommand{\ThePoints}{\FindPoints{#1}}
  \begin{exercise}[points=\ThePoints]\input{#1}
  \end{exercise}
  \IfFileExists{#1-sol.tex}{
    \begin{solution}
    \input{#1-sol}
  \end{solution}
  }{\wlog{#1-sol.tex not found! No solution produced.}}
}

\xsimsetup{%
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise},%
  exercise/template = runin,%
}%

\begin{document}
\inputexofiche{exo01}
\inputexofiche{exo02}
\inputexofiche{exo03}
\begin{center}
  \gradingtable[template=default*]
\end{center}
\end{document}


So I would like to try to define the points property with the \SetExerciseProperty command (I have to say that I use this technique with custom properties and it's working fine). When the string returned by the Python routine is empty, no points are attributed which is good. However, it fails in two ways :

Number 0 is set to the points property instead of the good amount of points;
Even exercise with no points property are in the grading table...

Even when I try \SetExerciseProperty{points}{8} within the exercise environment, it fails...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}%
\RequirePackage{pyluatex}
\begin{python}
  def findpoints(f):
    with open(f+".tex","r") as fi:
      id = []
      for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("% @Points"):
          id.append(ln[2:])
    if len(id) != 0:
      return id[0].split("@Points ",2)[1]
    else:
      return ''
\end{python}
\newcommand{\FindPoints}[1]{\pyc{print(findpoints("#1"))}}
\newcommand\SetPoints[1]{\SetExerciseProperty{points}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ThePoints}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\inputexofiche}{ m } {%
\renewcommand{\ThePoints}{\FindPoints{#1}}
  \begin{exercise}
    \IfStrEq{\ThePoints}{}{}{\SetPoints{\ThePoints}} % 
    \IfStrEq{\ThePoints}{}{}{\texttt{ThePoints : \ThePoints}} % <-- \ThePoints is well defined !!!

    \input{#1}
  \end{exercise}
  \IfFileExists{#1-sol.tex}{
    \begin{solution}
    \input{#1-sol}
  \end{solution}
  }{\wlog{#1-sol.tex not found! No solution produced.}}
}

\xsimsetup{%
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise},%
  exercise/template = runin,%
}%

\begin{document}
\inputexofiche{exo01}
\inputexofiche{exo02}
\inputexofiche{exo03}
\begin{center}
  \gradingtable[template=default*]
\end{center}
\end{document}


Here is the code for the three example exercises (they are in separated files):
% @Points 8
This is a test.

% @Points 7
This is another test.

This is another test without points.

Question
Does anyone know how to accomplish my goals which is :

Set the correct amount of points to the exrcise (the one that is fetched in the metadata of the exercise by the Python routine).
An exercise with no points property should not appear in the grading table.

Thank you in advance for answering!
